# Filtering data at datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, filter

I bind a dataset to a datagrid wpf like this

```
    DataSet d = Database.getBabies();
            babies = d.Tables[0].DefaultView;
      dataGridBabies.ItemsSource=babies;
```

Which is the best way to filter the data?(without running database query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XAML:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="MySource" Source="{Binding Path=MyDataBase}" Filter="OnCollectionViewSourceFilter">
```